# Postgres Show Time Availability

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime, gaps-and-islands

I'd like to ask if there is a built-in query to fetch date time availability in PostgreSQL.

Below are my table:

| Room Name | Book Start Date | Book End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Room A | 09-May-2022 09:00 | 09-May-2022 11:00 |
| Room A | 09-May-2022 12:30 | 09-May-2022 13:00 |
| Room A | 09-May-2022 15:00 | 09-May-2022 16:00 |
| Room B | 09-May-2022 09:00 | 09-May-2022 11:00 |
| Room B | 09-May-2022 11:30 | 09-May-2022 12:00 |
| Room B | 09-May-2022 15:30 | 09-May-2022 16:00 |

The requirement is to show the availability of each room from time range 06:00 - 18:00 to be like:

| Room Name | Available From | Available To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Room A | 09-May-2022 06:00 | 09-May-2022 09:00 |
| Room A | 09-May-2022 11:00 | 09-May-2022 12:30 |
| Room A | 09-May-2022 13:00 | 09-May-2022 15:00 |
| Room A | 09-May-2022 16:00 | 09-May-2022 18:00 |
| Room B | 09-May-2022 06:00 | 09-May-2022 09:00 |
| Room B | 09-May-2022 11:00 | 09-May-2022 11:30 |
| Room B | 09-May-2022 12:00 | 09-May-2022 15:30 |
| Room B | 09-May-2022 16:00 | 09-May-2022 18:00 |

I was just thinking if this is possible to do this by using only one query instead of writing additional code in the backend.

Thank you!

Comment: I'd recommend you write backend code or stored function for this. When you do that, you can write comments in your code to make it easy for the next person to maintain the code.

Answer (score 2):

That can be done easily and conveniently with the multirange types new in PostgreSQL v14. You construct a `tsrange` from the end points of each row using the `tsrange()` function, aggregate them into a `tsmultirange` using the `range_agg` aggregate function and subtract the result from the range of your choice. Finally, you can use `unnest` to turn the resulting multirange into a table of ranges.

Comment: I find this solution very interesting, but can't imagine a possible example. Could you provide one?